# boost unordered_map fail to find key

Tags: boost, unordered-map

It sounds wired. But I cannot think of the cause of it.
The situation is that there is boost::unordered_map (key=std::string, value=std::string) which stores the exchange order ID and internal order ID.

I add a new entry by using operator [] i.e. map[key] = value
When I try to find the key by using find().

It is fine except around 14:xx while the program start to run at 9:00AM for last two days. the key cannot be found while it is supposed to insert into the map. so what I suspect is related to the map size.

Is it possible for a hash map lose its entry during re-hasing?

PS no multi-thread issue as there is a lock protecting the map

Comment: What is the data type of your key?

Comment: key is string and value is string

Comment: A string object (like `std::string`) or a string literal?

Comment: Very odd then. This shouldn't happen unless there's some hash collision.

Comment: since the hash map does not only compare the hash value, I don't quite understand why one entry is lost during hash collision.

Comment: Just my assumption, don't weight it in too much. Never had such an issue to be honest.